# Can I clone the Number object in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototype, javascript-objects, prototypal-inheritance

Let's say the following javascript object represents a table-row in my website:

```
var oProduct = (function () {
    function oProduct(opts) {
        var o = opts || {},
            self = this;

        self.id = o.id || ''; // 423
        self.desc = o.desc || ''; // "Some product"
        self.price = o.price || 0; // 99.98
        self.currentDiscount = o.discount || 0; // .15
        self.prevDiscount = o.prevDiscount || 0; // .10
        self.nextDiscount = o.nextDiscount || 0; // .125
    }

    return oProduct;
})();
```

---

### What I tried doing...

Now I want to add a method to each of the "discount" values that converts the decimal value into a string that my users are familiar with. So something like `.15` would be converted into `ADD'L 15%`

I'd really like to be able to attach the function to the oProduct's discount properties using some kind of prototypical inheritance, but I'm not so good with the prototypes. My first thought was to clone javascript's `Number` object (or is it a function?) and add the method to its prototype like this:

```
function discountString(myval) {
            var a = $.extend(true, {}, Number);
            a.prototype.toTableDisplay = function () { return convertSmallPercentToEasyPercent(this) }; // this function is elsewhere. I don't think you'll need it, but let me know if I'm wrong.
            return a(myval);
        };
```

I'd then change the oProduct object constructor to this:

```
var oProduct = (function () {
    function oProduct(opts) {
        var o = opts || {},
            self = this;

        self.id = o.id || ''; // 423
        self.desc = o.desc || ''; // "Some product"
        self.price = o.price || 0; // 99.98
        self.currentDiscount = discountString(o.discount || 0); // .15
        self.prevDiscount = discountString(o.prevDiscount || 0); // .10
        self.nextDiscount = discountString(o.nextDiscount || 0); // .125
    }

    return oProduct;
})();
```

and then use the method like this:

```
var cellData = myProductVariable.prevDiscount.toTableDisplay(); // returns "ADD'L 10%"
```

...but clearly I have not quite grasped the concept of prototypes just yet, because I tried about 500 different ways to make it work, but couldn't ever get it working properly. I know I could just add the method directly to the `Number.prototype` object like I've seen people do all the time, but I'd rather not add this method to *all* numbers...just the ones on this table.

I've done something similar to this using objects, but not the `Number` object. I'm not even sure if it is possible.

---

### My Question...

So I guess my questions are as follows:

1. I know I can clone/copy an object using $.extend(), but can I do the
   same with `Number`?
2. And if not, can anyone recommend a better approach to this problem?

Comment: Not sure why you need the IIFE, and `self`... looks redundant

Comment: Could you just not myNewNumber = Number(myOldNumber) or myNewNumber = myOldNumber * 1?

Comment: Me thinks it would be better to not add crap to the `Number.prototype` but rather use a function `func(number)` that returns the string, you could even bake in the `|| 0` check

Comment: I would advice you to look at [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Number/prototype)

Comment: To answer your first question: No, `$.extend` cannot clone/copy functions. For your second question, have a look at the duplicate.

Comment: @elclanrs The object is actually much larger than that, and includes code inside and outside of the constructor. I was just trying to provide an accurate example.